# The page isn't redirecting properly in Wamp Server

Tags: php, loops, http-redirect, redirect

I uploaded Php file on online, that is login system that is working properly, but that same code its not working in localhost. I am using WAMP Server. It always says "The page isn't redirecting properly".

```html
This is My .htaccess file

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^74\.208\.90\.60
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost:8080/gdev
RewriteRule (.*) [localhost] [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Please post some code. How are we supposed to diagnose the problem without any code? If you have a .htaccess file, please post it. Also post any PHP code that does any redirecting.

Comment: i hope it will help you

Comment: We don't need a wall of code; we just need code sufficient to help you find the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thanks Ed, I will do like that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with this:

- Drop the `\`s in your first `RewriteCond`.
- Your second `RewriteCond` makes no sense. The only portion of `localhost:8080/gdev` that is relevant to `%{HTTP_HOST}` is `localhost`. You can't use this one rule to check the host, the port, and the path.
- Your `RewriteRule` doesn't make sense. Redirecting to `[localhost]` is like redirecting to `http://whatever/[localhost]`. It doesn't change the port.

I'm not 100% what you're trying to do, but I'd suggest you start by reading up on [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directives.